# How do I assign an external user to my EC2 windows instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to assign a new user to my EC2 windows instance. I have tried setting up an IAM role, and IAM user, but I can't seem to figure out assigning either a role or the user to my instance.

I followed what most have recommended: creating an image of my existing instance and assigning an IAM role, but I am not sure how that user will be able to access my instance.

Secondly, if I were to create a new IAM user with administrative permissions and issue them the console's URL. Would they be able to navigate to the EC2 instance pane and launch it from there?

My aim is just to provide a user access to my instance if they were to launch it from either a RDP client or their commandLine...any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: IAM accounts and roles have nothing at all to do with Windows server logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mark-b correctly wrote in comment, IAM roles/accounts have nothing at all to do with Windows logins.

Imagine an IAM role as the role which is assigned by default to all users on your Windows machine (actually the role is assigned to the instance itself). They can leverage this role and perform different operations in Amazon, like viewing S3 buckets, controlling EC2 instances and basically do everything what you could do with AWS Console, however only to extent that the IAM role allows.

The Windows users have nothing to do with that (despite 'the default' behavior as I wrote). You have to create a new local user in Windows and allow the RDP connections.

To allow RDP access make sure:

- security group for the EC2 instance is allowing needed ports/addresses for RDP usage,
- Windows firewall allows RDP connections,
- Windows server has RDP feature turned on.